# What does this declaration mean?

Tags: java, generics

For this declaration

```
final Map<?, ?> qBuilders;
```

what does it mean?

Answer (score 4):

It declares the class attribute `qBuilders`. This variable *must* be initialized in a constructor and you can't assign another value to that attribute afterwards (but you can change the map keys and values - you just can't exchange the entire map).

`Map` is a generic interface, `<?,?>` are the *type parameters*  for this attributes. `?` is a *wildcard* and just tells, that this map accepts any java type for keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

It's a blank final. You can assign to the variable once but you cannot reassign the variable after that, however it does not render the qBuilders map immutable. You can still call its method and use the map as usual. See the explanation on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

While your question is fairly vague, the `final` keyword, in the context of a variable, means the variable can only be assigned once. If the variable is a field of a class, it has to be assigned in the constructor of said class.

Answer (score 0):

**?** - It means any java type (String, Integer...)